# is it possible to nest to class existing enum

Tags: c++, class, enums, using

I have enum in some header file. Is it possible to nest to the class existing enum?

Explanation:

some headerfile.h:

```
enum someEnum
{
someValue
/*other values*/
};
```

other header:

```
#include "headerfile.h"
class someClass
{
 public:
  //using enum someEnum; //don't work as I want
 };
```

I want that someValue will be accesible as

```
     someClass::someValue
```

So my question is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well one way would be to do this:

```
class someClass
{
 public:

#include "headerfile.h"

  //using enum someEnum; //don't work as I want

 };
```

not pretty but works.

Comment: Seems that is the only way.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can nest that `enum` definition:

```
class someClass {
public:
    enum someEnum {
        someValue
    };
};
```

Then you can access this enumerations just like the way you wanted:

```
someClass::someEnum X = someClass::someValue;
```

If, however, what you wanted was to create a member variable typed `someEnum`, you can do it either by just supplying `someEnum` as a type, or nesting the enumeration and putting the variable name before the semicolon.

Comment: I know about nesting(I just forget this term when wrote this question), but I can't  move that enum from his header, it must stay there. the question is is it possible to nest to the class existing enum.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to include the library inside the class definition.